# Oddo 9 - "Create and Edit" option in a many2one field

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

When there is a many2one field in a model in odoo, it is possible to select "create and edit" from the dropdown menu. This brings up a window which allows you to create a new record. How can I pre-populate one of the field in this new  record?
In the model "res.partner", I have:

```
name = fields.Char(string="Name",size=32)
abc_contract_id = fields.Many2one('abc_sale.vendor.contract','Contract')
```

In the model "abc_sale.vendor.contract", I have:

```
abc_vendor_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Vendor',required=True)
```

I want to pre-populate value of "name" to "abc_vendor_id" as I click "create and edit" option in abc_contract_id

Comment: the field name is in abc_sale.vendor.contract ?

Comment: No. Its in the model "res.partner" as I have mentioned above.

Comment: so you want to pass the value from this view to second view to third view what kind of inheritance you are using

Comment: I have "name" and a many2one field "abc_contract_id" in res.partner. I also have a many2one field "abc_vendor_id" in the model "abc_sale.vendor.contract".  I want to pre-populate value of "name" to "abc_vendor_id" as I click "create and edit" option in "abc_contract_id".

Comment: with what value ?

Comment: value of the field "name" from "res.partner" to "abc_vendor_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<field name='abc_contract_id' context="{'default_abc_vendor_id': active_id}"/>
```

Adding active id like this, resulted in correct output for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add context in the default action to the form view of your many2one model like:-

```
<record id="custom_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Maintenance Requests</field>
        <field name="res_model">Your_model</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{
            'search_default_category_id': [active_id],
            'default_category_id': active_id,
            'default_fieldname': 'your_custom_value' or anyfieldname
        }</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: unfortunately I have tried many variations of this exact solution, and can't set *any* fields of the res.partner form

Answer (score 0):

To populate `abc_vendor_id` when you click `Create and Edit` option in `abc_contract_id` use `context` to pass the default values:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="base_view_partner_form_inherit">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" position="after">
                    <field name="abc_contract_id" context="{'default_abc_vendor_id': id}"/>
                    <field name="id" invisible="True"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```